# Accordion messing up when dropping to new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've plugged a few pieces of jQuery UI together, and for the most part everything is working. I have an issue though, I have a page of tabs and in each table are sortable accordion elements...

Everything seems to work fine until I move an element to a new tab, it seems to lose what it's parent is. When I expand a dropped accordion, it either goes outside the container, or doesn't show at all, it depends on whether or not the accordion was open when dropped into a new tab.

I've put together a jsfiddle example of my code. Here's my jquery and a link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/33Wzs/6/ a few seconds of moving elements back and forth should give you an idea of what's going on.

My Html

```
<div id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-pane">
        <div id="accordion">
            <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset">
                <li>
                    <header><span class="handle pull-left cursor-move">[move]</span> Item 1</header>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Item 1</h4>

                        <p>Here is some text to go with <em>item #</em>. How does this work?</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <header><span class="handle pull-left cursor-move">[move]</span> Item 2</header>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Item 1</h4>

                        <p>Here is some text to go with <em>item #</em>. How does this work?</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <header><span class="handle pull-left cursor-move">[move]</span> Item 3</header>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Item 1</h4>

                        <p>Here is some text to go with <em>item #</em>. How does this work?</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <header><span class="handle pull-left">[move]</span> Item 4</header>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Item 1</h4>

                        <p>Here is some text to go with <em>item #</em>. How does this work?</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div id="accordion2">
            <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable ui-helper-reset"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        header: 'header',
        active: false,
        heightStyle: 'content'
    });
    $("#accordion2").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        header: 'header',
        active: false,
        heightStyle: 'content'
    });
});

$(function () {
    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").sortable({
        axis: "x",
        stop: function () {
            tabs.tabs("refresh");
        }
    });
});

$(function () {

    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable().disableSelection();
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable("option", "handle", ".handle");

    var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
    var $tab_items = $("ul:first li", $tabs).droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        accept: ".connectedSortable li",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var $item = $(this);
            var $list = $($item.find("a").attr("href"))
                .find(".connectedSortable");
            ui.draggable.hide("fast", function () {
                $tabs.tabs("option", "active", $tab_items.index($item));
                $(this).appendTo($list).show("fast");
            });

        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I think I found the culprit. In you first tab you have a plain <li> tag in your source code. After moving one item to the other tab, the other tab uses this li tag: `<li class="" style="height: 43px; width: 522px; display: list-item;">` When i remove the style attribute in the inspector the display is correct.

Comment: @edwardmp I don't think that's anything I can change....

Comment: Well at least you know the actual problem. So it has to do something with the height..

Comment: I did some messing around in the inspector, noticed that removing the height fixed it. I just don't know how to stop jquery ui from adding the height

Comment: I already told you that removing the height fixed it..

Comment: The height is added by jquery ui itself. I'm not the one adding the height.

Comment: I know it is added by jQuery. I don't know the actual answer, but I point you in the right direction for searching a solution

Comment: I know, thanks for that.. But I still haven't found the answer. I've been scouring the jquery ui documentation and haven't found anything that works yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on... just under

```
$(this).appendTo($list).show("fast");
```

I added

```
$(this).removeAttr('style');
```

and it solved my issue. I still don't know where the styles are coming from... here is a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/33Wzs/7/